# How do I make a discord bot that tags

Tags: discord, discord.py

How do I make a discord bot that tags a @role when someone joins into a voice channel?
Example:
@role {user} has joined the `Support 1 Channel`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # Checking if the member has joined channel
    if before.voice is None and after.voice is not None:
        # Getting the channel and a role
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        role = member.guild.get_role(role_id)

        # Sending some info 
        await channel.send(f'{role.mention} {member.mention} has joined `{str(after.voice.channel)}`')
```